# Click on chart to expand more information - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart.js to create a simple pie chart, what I want to know is how a user can interact with the chart so if they click or hover on a certain section, it will expand to give them more information at the bottom.

I've scoured the internet and I can only find pop-up notification (click events). What I really want is a section to appear at the bottom with up to a paragraph of information.

Here is an example of a pie chart - say I wanted "Azure" to read "Azure 45" on hover and then expand on the bottom with some further info like "Azure is a light shade of blue that falls in the color wheel between blue and cyan."

Here is my code - I hope what I'm trying to convey makes sense - thank you in advance!

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Navy", "Ruby", "Emerald", "Orange", "Azure"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: ["#0074D9", "#FF4136", "#2ECC40", "#FF851B", "#7FDBFF"],
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 45],
        }]
    },    

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title:{
        display: true, 
        text: "Colour test"
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Displaying additional information below a chart is probably out of scope of Chart.js, so you will need take care of that yourself by e.g. placing a separate DIV below the chart which gets updated dynamically. So the question is, how to trigger the update?

I haven't found a way to listen to hover events on a segment. However, Chart.js offers a range of callbacks for the tooltips, which are triggered whenever the user hovers a certain element, see: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks

You could hook into one of these, like so:

```
const chartOptions = {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                const dataSet = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                const value = dataSet.data[tooltipItem.index];

                // Now trigger a data update / display of a separate DIV with your information.

                // Don't forget to return your desired label value.
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```